# Count 2 different columns in one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am facing a problem and getting incorrect results. I'd like to count records that have leavedates and deceaseddates for each year and display them in one table.

This is my query so far:

```
select  year(leavedate) as leave_year,  count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave ,  count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from clients
where leavedate is not null and DeceasedDate is not null 
group by year(leavedate),year(DeceasedDate)
order by 1 desc
```

This is the goal I'd like like to have:

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| Year | Cnt_leave | Cnt_dod |
+------+-----------+---------+
| 2018 |       542 |    5685 |
| 2017 |      8744 |    5622 |
| 2016 |       556 |     325 |
| etc  |           |         |
+------+-----------+---------+
```

Should I do it in two separate select statements or is it possible to do it in one?
I'd appreciate a feedback!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful for us to help you easily.

Comment: Google `SQL Conditional Aggregation`.   Lots of examples.

Comment: so if you're where clause requires both dates to be not null; then you're only going to count those records where both are not null; and thus the counts would match.  Is that what you're seeing?   Why do you need the where clause? or at least both parts?  Or should the `AND` be an `OR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
with
l as (
  select year(leavedate) as y, count(*) as c
  from clients 
  group by year(leavedate)
),
d as (
  select year(deceaseddate) as y, count(*) as c
  from clients 
  group by year(deceaseddate)
)
select
  coalesce(l.y, d.y) as year,
  coalesce(l.c, 0) as cnt_leave,
  coalesce(d.c, 0) as cnt_dod
from l
full outer join d on l.y = d.y
order by coalesce(l.y, d.y) desc
```

Comment: I actually did something similar with CTE's:    with leaves as (
select  year(leavedate) as leave_year,  count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave
from clients
where leavedate is not null 
group by year(leavedate)
)
, deads as (
select  year(DeceasedDate) as dod_year,  count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from clients
where DeceasedDate is not null 
group by year(DeceasedDate)
)

select leave_year, cnt_leave, cnt_dod  from leaves l
left join deads d on l.leave_year = d.dod_year
order by 1 desc

Comment: Your results will look interesting if there are years with "deceased" values but no "leave" values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Holy cow. Good catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you are looking for something like this :

```
select year(leavedate) as leave_year,  sum(case leavedate when null then 0 else 1 end) as cnt_leave, 
sum(case DeceasedDate when null then 0 else 1 end) as cnt_dod 
from clients
where leavedate is not null or DeceasedDate is not null 
group by year(leavedate)
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work since a client can have both "leave" and "deceased" dates in different years.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to count in two steps as `Year(LeaveDate)` is not related to `Year(DeceasedDate)`; but you combine those SELECTs via some CTE construction.

In fact, there are (at least) two ways you can do this, not sure which one will be the better performer; you'll need to try to figure out what works best on your data.

```
SELECT client_id = 1, LeaveDate = Convert(datetime, '20080118'), DeceasedDate = Convert(datetime, '20090323')
  INTO #test
 UNION ALL SELECT client_id = 2, LeaveDate = '20100118', DeceasedDate = '20100323'
 UNION ALL SELECT client_id = 3, LeaveDate = '20100118', DeceasedDate = '20120323'

;WITH src 
   AS (SELECT * 
         FROM #test 
        WHERE LeaveDate IS NOT NULL 
          AND DeceasedDate IS NOT NULL),    
      leave
   AS (SELECT yr = Year(LeaveDate), cnt = COUNT(*) FROM src GROUP BY Year(LeaveDate)),
      deceased
   AS (SELECT yr = Year(DeceasedDate), cnt = COUNT(*) FROM src GROUP BY Year(DeceasedDate))

SELECT yr              = ISNULL(l.yr, d.yr),
       cntLeaveDate    = ISNULL(l.cnt, 0),
       cntDeceasedDate = ISNULL(d.cnt, 0)
  FROM leave l
  FULL OUTER JOIN deceased d
               ON d.yr = l.yr
 ORDER BY 1 DESC

;WITH src 
   AS (SELECT * 
         FROM #test 
        WHERE LeaveDate IS NOT NULL 
          AND DeceasedDate IS NOT NULL),    
      years
   AS (SELECT DISTINCT yr = Year(LeaveDate) FROM src
        UNION -- Do not UNION ALL here, you want to avoid doubles!
       SELECT DISTINCT yr = Year(DeceasedDate) FROM src)

SELECT yr,
       cntLeaveDate    = SUM ( CASE WHEN Year(LeaveDate)    = yr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       cntDeceasedDate = SUM ( CASE WHEN Year(DeceasedDate) = yr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM years, #test
 WHERE LeaveDate IS NOT NULL 
   AND DeceasedDate IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY yr
  ORDER BY 1 DESC

  DROP TABLE #test
```

Comment: select '18 jan 2008' isn't ANSI standards and can result in a varchar datatype instead of a date. This isn't how you shoulq insert dates. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b572cfc5dc25b4d5856e3588fa9d6371

Comment: Agreed, adapted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` for this . . . I think it is the simplest solution:

```
select  year(dte) as year,  sum(isleave) as num_leaves, sum(isdeceased) as numdeceased
from clients c cross apply
     (values (leavedate, 1, 0),
             (deceaseddate, 0, 1)
     ) v(dte, isleave, isdeceased)
where dte is not null 
group by year(dte)
order by 1 desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

**[SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d62d7efaff026aaeca1c14dc71e16344)**

Based on your comments, all you need is to remove the where clause and limit the group by.

```
select  
    year(leavedate) as leave_year,
     count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave ,  
     count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from clients
--where leavedate is not null and DeceasedDate is not null 
group by year(leavedate) --,year(DeceasedDate)
--order by 1 desc
```

Or, if your data could have `NULL`'s in either column, which I assume above and thus omitted the `where` clause you'd want:

```
select  
    coalesce(year(leavedate),year(DeceasedDate)) as the_year,
     count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave ,  
     count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from clients
--where leavedate is not null and DeceasedDate is not null 
group by coalesce(year(leavedate),year(DeceasedDate))
--order by 1 desc
```

Here's the example:

```
declare @clients table (leavedate date null, DeceasedDate date null)
insert into @clients
values
('20180101',NULL)
,(null,'20170101')
,('20150101','20150101')

select  
    year(leavedate) as leave_year,
     count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave ,  
     count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from @clients
--where leavedate is not null and DeceasedDate is not null 
group by year(leavedate) --,year(DeceasedDate)
--order by 1 desc


select  
    coalesce(year(leavedate),year(DeceasedDate)) as the_year,
     count(year(leavedate)) as cnt_leave ,  
     count(year(DeceasedDate)) as cnt_dod 
from @clients
--where leavedate is not null and DeceasedDate is not null 
group by coalesce(year(leavedate),year(DeceasedDate))
--order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Don't see how this would work. Suppose he has 2 records with L:20010101, D:20050101 and L:20070101, D:20070101 then where would your 2007 result come from?

Comment: The first non-null, so leavedate. Want me to show you? Specifically the second answer. The first was an assumption of the data... wince the OP didn't provide sample data

Comment: maybe this will help @deroby https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d62d7efaff026aaeca1c14dc71e16344

Comment: I tried it on my #test data (cf below) and it surely didn't return a value for 2012 or 2009. Also, I wonder why the `ORDER BY` is 'useless'. Lots of people prefer to look at ordered lists or reports. (I'll admit that some sample data would have avoided som 'guessing')

Comment: As you can see from my fiddle... the second query will work there isn't data for each year for both dates. If there were data for both dates for all years, the first would work too

Comment: The first one will not work when `LeaveDate` and `DeceasedDate` are in different years. And,. actually, no, the second one won't work when there is data for both columns, so in a way the 'too' is kind off applicable =). Try to apply this data set to the fiddle: `('20080101','20090323'),('20100118','20100323'),('20100118','20120323')`.

Comment: Assumptions on the dataset... we can assume things ALL DAY LONG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184645/discussion-between-deroby-and-scsimon).